# Creating Lightning Platform Starter License User In Scratch Org?

Tags: apex, lightning, user, licenses

what is the confi.json we need to add for enabling the Lightning Platform Starter license in our scratch org?

we want to check what are all feature users will lose when we downgrade to the Lightning Platform Starter license?

Does the Lightning Platform Starter license user has access to Flexi pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightning Platform Starter is not a **user** license type, it's an **org** type. Use the `orgType` value of `Professional` to get an approximation of what you'll get in a Lightning Platform Starter org. Or, you can just sign up for a free 30 day trial and leave it when you're done. The trial is basically the same as the real thing, except you're limited to how many emails you can send via automations per day.

Comment: does that mean a company cannot purchase Lightning Platform Starer licenses if their org is running on Enterprise Edition?

Comment: @dev4life Correct. Think of it as an all-or-nothing upgrade. You get a bunch of cool features when you move up from Starter, but you no longer get to have Starter licenses.

Comment: for the record, I have checked with an official Salesforce AE. Platform Starter are available on Enterprise Edition